# Unit testing an event in HttpModule

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, c#-4.0

I have an CustomHttp module in my application to remove the unwanted response headers as below.

```
 public class RemoveServerHeadersModule : IHttpModule
        {
            public void Init(HttpApplication context)
            {
                context.PreSendRequestHeaders += OnPreSendRequestHeaders;
            }

            public void Dispose() { }

            public void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Powered-By");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
            }
        }
```

I need to write unit test for this .

Tried few like below but unable to do that , getting error.

```
 HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "", "");
 StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
 HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
 HttpContext httpContextMock = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);

 var application = new Mock<HttpApplication>();
 application.Setup(ct => ct.Context).Returns(httpContextMock);

 var module = new RemoveServerHeadersModule();
 HttpApplication httpApplication = new HttpApplication();
 module.Init(httpApplication);
 module.OnPreSendRequestHeaders(httpApplication, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Getting error when trying to set the Context in HttpApplication.
Please could you help me out

Answer (score 2):

Per [guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet-and-what-to-do-instead#presend) by Microsoft you shouldn't be using the OnPreSendRequestHeaders event

> You can use the PreSendRequestHeaders and PreSendRequestContext events
>   with native IIS modules, but do not use them with managed modules that
>   implement IHttpModule. Setting these properties can cause issues with
>   asynchronous requests.

If you can move to a different event, you can then use the techniques shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648610/asp-net-nunit-good-unit-testing-strategy-for-httpmodule-using-net-4)

Which links to this old [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20151219105430/http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/unit-testable-httpmodule-and-httphandler)

where you create a BaseHttpModule to then create events where you can pass the context into the handler

```
public abstract class BaseHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += (sender, e) => OnBeginRequest(new HttpContextWrapper(((HttpApplication) sender).Context));
        context.Error += (sender, e) => OnError(new HttpContextWrapper(((HttpApplication) sender).Context));
        context.EndRequest += (sender, e) => OnEndRequest(new HttpContextWrapper(((HttpApplication) sender).Context));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnBeginRequest(HttpContextBase context)
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnError(HttpContextBase context)
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnEndRequest(HttpContextBase context)
    {
    }
}
```

Then your class becomes

```
public class RemoveServerHeadersModule : BaseHttpModule
{
    public override void OnBeginRequest(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Powered-By");
        context.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
        context.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
        context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
    }
}
```

and your test is something like

```
        var fakeContext = A.Fake<HttpContextBase>();
        var fakeRequest = A.Fake<HttpRequestBase>();
        var fakeResponse = A.Fake<HttpResponseBase>();

        A.CallTo(() => fakeResponse.Headers).Returns( /*put your headers here*/);

        A.CallTo(() => fakeContext.Response).Returns(fakeResponse);
        A.CallTo(() => fakeContext.Request).Returns(fakeRequest);

        var _sut = new RemoveServerHeadersModule();
        _sut.OnBeginRequest(fakeContext);

        //your header checks.
```

Comment: The OP is using an `HttpModule`, not a `Controller`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.
Have one query..Do i need to attach other events(OnError, OnEndRequest)  apart from OnBeginRequest since iam using 
OnBeginRequest only in RemoveServerHeadersModule.
Please let me know

Comment: you shouldn't have to implement the other even handlers unless you are going to use them

Comment: After modifying the event from OnPreSendRequestHeaders to OnBeginRequest only the "Server" key is getting removed from the header.While debugging the web api response i could see only "Server" key is present in the response.Please suggest how to modify to get all server headers in the web api response.

Comment: if all you really need to do is to remove those asp.net headers, you can do it with the web.config without ever writing a custom handler.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078756/how-to-delete-iis-custom-headers-like-x-powered-by-asp-net-from-response